# Inherited class in Swift 5.3 is calling upper class init, not the expected inherited init

Tags: swift, class, inheritance

i stumbled over a thing in Swift.
I inherited the class `UIAlertController` to switch between iPadOS an

```
class myUIAlertController: UIAlertController {
convenience init(title: String?, message: String?, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style, interfaceIdiom: UIUserInterfaceIdiom? = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom) {
    self.init(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: interfaceIdiom == .pad ? .alert : preferredStyle)
}
```

Now I've the problem, when I create a instance from this class like so:

```
let actionsheet = myUIAlertController(
        title: "Profile.Change-Image.ActionSheet.Title".localized,
        message: nil,
        preferredStyle: .actionSheet
    )
```

it calls the init from `UIAlertController` **and not `myUIAlertController`**

Tried this:

```
let actionsheet = myUIAlertController(
        title: "Profile.Change-Image.ActionSheet.Title".localized,
        message: nil,
        preferredStyle: .actionSheet,
        interfaceIdiom: UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom
    )
```

This works but I want to know why I need the extra argument `interfaceIdiom`?

Comment: From the documentation: `Important - The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing.`

Comment: If you just want to force the the style, you could use an extension on `UIAlertController` and making a factory method.

Comment: cheers, missed the yellow **important** box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has *nothing* to do with the documentated restriction that `The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing.`.

Independend of the base class, you'll always run in this kind of problems when the compiler has multiple overloaded functions to choose from.

Your example is exactly like the following:

```
class Base {
    convenience init(value1:Int) {
        print("Base::init(\(value1))")
        self.init()
    }
}

class Derived : Base {
    convenience init(value1:Int, value2:Int = 123) {
        print("Derived::init (\(value1), \(value2))")
        self.init(value1:value1)  // no recursion here!
    }   
}

var b  = Base(value1:42)                // prints: Base::init(42)
var d1 = Derived(value1:42)             // prints: Base::init(42), not Derived::init (42, 123)
var d2 = Derived(value1:42, value2:99)  // prints: Derived::init (42, 99) ...
```

The question is: Why does `var d = Derived(value1:42)` call the base classes init and not the convenience initializer of Derived, with a default parameter `value2 = 123`?

The reason for this is how the compiler chooses the functions if they are ambigious.
Think of two functions:

```
func foo() { print ("foo()")}
func foo(_ value:Int = 42) { print ("foo(\(value))")}
```

What should happen if someone calls `foo()`? Both functions might be valid, so the compiler has to decide which to choose. And the compiler will choose the function that is *most specific match*.

The first `foo` *always* takes zero parameters. The second `foo` *sometimes* takes zero and *sometimes* takes one parameter. Hence, the first function is *more specific* than the second, because it always and only takes zero parameters. Therefore:

```
foo() // prints foo(), not foo(42)
```